# is it possible to separate the effect of changes in numerator and denominator on the value of the ratio between the two?

Tags: statistics

If a ratio r is equal to A/(B+C)

and A is 1 in period 1 and 2 in period 2, B is 3 in period 1 and 2 in period 2 and C is 4 in period 1 and 5 in period 2. Then we have that the ratio goes from 0,14285714 in period 1 to 0,28571429 in period 2. The percentage change is 100%.

How can I know how much of the change is attributed to the change in A, B and C?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so I would like to know how much of the 100% change is due to the change in A, how much due to the change in B, and how much to the change in C. In the end I would like to be able to say that if A has increased 100% from period 1 to 2 that has contributed to the change of r by, for instance, 55%. I am sorry, I am not so sure how to make myself clearer.

Comment: What is the context in which this question arose?

Comment: I plot the evolution of a ratio over time (profits over total assets, where total assets have three components -so the ratio is r= P/(A+B+C)) And I would like to be able to say for each period how much of the change in the ratio is due to each of the components of the ratio

Comment: So this is basically the domain of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_analysis -- there are lots of possible methods, depending on your situation.  One elementary thing would be to compute the different partial derivatives of your multivariate function, scaled by the change of each variable -- but whether this is appropriate to your context is not clear.